# Efficiently combine (AND) groups of columns in a logical matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking for an efficient way to combine selected columns in a logical matrix by "`AND`ing" them together and ending up with a new matrix. An example of what I am looking for:

```
matrixData <- rep(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 8)
exampleMatrix <- matrix(matrixData, nrow=6, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
exampleMatrix
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The columns to be ANDed to each other are specified in a numeric vector of length `ncol(exampleMatrix)`, where the columns to be grouped together ANDed have the same value (a value from `1` to `n`, where `n <= ncol(exampleMatrix)` and every value in `1:n` is used at least once). The resulting matrix should have the columns in order from `1:n`. For example, if the vector that specifies the column groups is

```
colGroups <- c(3, 2, 2, 1)
```

Then the resulting matrix would be

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Where in the resulting matrix

```
[,1] = exampleMatrix[,4] 
[,2] = exampleMatrix[,2] & exampleMatrix[,3]
[,3] = exampleMatrix[,1]
```

My current way of doing this looks basically like this:

```
finalMatrix <- matrix(TRUE, nrow=nrow(exampleMatrix), ncol=3)
for (i in 1:3){
    selectedColumns <- exampleMatrix[,colGroups==i, drop=FALSE]
    finalMatrix[,i] <- rowSums(selectedColumns)==ncol(selectedColumns)
}
```

Where `rowSums(selectedColumns)==ncol(selectedColumns)` is an efficient way to AND all of the columns of a matrix together.

My problem is that I am doing this on very big matrices (millions of rows) and I am looking for any way to make this quicker. My first instinct would be to use `apply` in some way but I can't see any way to use that to improve efficiency as I am not performing the operation in the `for` loop many times  but instead it is the operation in the loop that is slow.

In addition, any tips to reduce memory allocation would be very useful, as I currently have to run `gc()` within the loop frequently to avoid running out of memory completely, and it is a very expensive operation that significantly slows everything down as well. Thanks!

For a more representative example, this is a much larger `exampleMatrix`:

```
matrixData <- rep(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 8e7)
exampleMatrix <- matrix(matrixData, nrow=6e7, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Henrik the data I have been using to benchmark the current answers as well as my original solution is now at the end of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example, I understand that there are very few columns and very many rows. In this case, it'll be efficient to just do a simple loop over `colGroups` (30% improvement over your suggestion):

```
for (jj in seq_along(colGroups)) 
  finalMatrix[ , colGroups[jj]] = 
    finalMatrix[ , colGroups[jj]] & exampleMatrix[ , jj]
```

I think it will be hard to beat this without parallelizing. This loop is parallelizable if there are more columns (though the parallelization will have to be done a bit carefully (in batches)).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this is an aggregation across columns using the `all` function. So if you `t`ranspose to rows, then use `colGroups` as the grouping factor to apply `all`, then `t`ranspose back to columns, you should get the intended result:

```
t(aggregate(t(exampleMatrix), list(colGroups), FUN=all)[-1])

#    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#V1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#V2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#V3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#V4  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#V5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#V6 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The `[-1]` just drops the group-identifier variable which you don't require in the final output.

If you're working with stupid big data, the by-group aggregation could be done in `data.table` as well:

```
library(data.table)
t(as.data.table(t(exampleMatrix))[, lapply(.SD,all), by=colGroups][,-1])
```

Comment: This is a super straightforward and elegant way to do this, but I am not seeing any time savings. With `nrow=6e7`, both solutions ran out of memory on my system , whereas  the solution from @michaelchirico took 66 seconds and mine took 5 seconds.

Comment: @WalkerintheCity - the issue would be the `t` for transposing the matrix I believe which means you have the original plus a copy of the whole object. Are you able to save the transposed copy (and remove the original) first and then work with it instead? Storing as rows or columns shouldn't make any real difference to storage size.

Comment: I am still running into a memory allocation issue after transposing `exampleMatrix` and removing the original. I am going to increase the memory limit and try it on a machine with more RAM.

Comment: @WalkerintheCity - the more I think about this, the `for` loop is actually an excellent way to do this as you only have to copy the needed chunks rather than work on (and potentially copy) a massive object.

Comment: I have been running this with more memory for more than 10 minutes (not yet finished) and I think my conclusion is that is is very slow. I am interested as to why that is and what is holding it up. I do suspect that my solution is already pretty speedy as I have spent a fair bit of time trying to optimize this chunk and it is quite the bottleneck.